# Button is not displaying in layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-relativelayout

I have made an Android activity. In this activity I have a `ListView` and a `Button`. I want to add the `Button` to the bottom of screen. I have tried so long but it's hidden from tabbar. My `xml` code is as below. Please help me.

**code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.eps.blancatours.uc.Header
        android:id="@+id/hdr_dest_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_main_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hdr_dest_list"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/dest_List"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn_next" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="#D41016"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` from `btn_next`

Comment: @GiruBhai-No change after removng it..!!!

Comment: clean your project and retry

Comment: try to change android:layout_height="wrap_content" of listview

Comment: @jollz-Still same problem remains..!!! :(

Comment: @user3820044 Add android:orientation="vertical" on your both RelativeLayouts see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25339929/991085)

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:orientation="vertical"` on your both RelativeLayouts as

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.eps.blancatours.uc.Header
        android:id="@+id/hdr_dest_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_main_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hdr_dest_list"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/dest_List"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn_next" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="#D41016"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And don't forget to clear the project.

Comment: Orientation is used by LinearLayout, not RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your main RelativeLayout with `</RelativeLayout>`.

For me your code works, you just have to close your relative layout.

Comment: Actually he did but @Elango removed and edited the original question

Comment: I just have forget to post closing bracket.and how can it works without enclosing bracket..:O

Comment: I get same layout like @Raviindra Singh posted. i just deleted <com.eps.blancatours.uc.Header> because I don't have this class, changed @string/next and closed RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes like below  -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/li"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

        <com.eps.blancatours.uc.Header
        android:id="@+id/hdr_dest_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        </LinearLayout>

       <ListView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_above="@+id/button1"

           android:id="@+id/list"
           android:padding="30dp"

           />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:background="#68bdb6"
             android:text="@string/Select" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Strange.. instead of header i am using imageview in linear layout and its working fine. Try to restart eclipse or clean your project once

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your main Relativelayout just close that layout button will appear below the listview

Comment: Actually he did but @Elango removed and edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It does working here, all I added is just **`</RelativeLayout>`** tag before the parent tag.
and my text in place of the **@String** reference.
also **Try changing android version when rendering layout**.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping `ListView` and `Button` with nested `RelativeLayout` is redundant. You could set you XML like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.eps.blancatours.uc.Header
        android:id="@+id/hdr_dest_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dest_List"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hdr_dest_list"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#D41016"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also use `match_parent` instead `fill_parent`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below inside Button

```
android:layout_below="@id/list"
```